# Custom Text on Cart and/or Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Does anyone know how I can add custom text under every product in the cart page and checkout page? I don’t want that text showing on the individual product pages – only on cart/checkout pages. It will be the same for every product e.g. “Lead time can be up to 8 weeks”

Thank you!

I know code needs to be added into functions.php file but I have no idea what

Comment: Are you using woocommerce blocks for cart page, checkout page? Or are you using woocommerce template files for cart page, checkout page?

Comment: Please note that stack overflow is not a free coding service: we expect you to better search and provide in your question your own custom real code attempt.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding requirement, mentioned in provided question, to add custom text "Lead time can be up to 8 weeks." for every product in woocommerce cart page, woocommerce checkout page, the following code can be put in theme functions.php file. If woocommerce template files are used for cart page, checkout page, then following code can be put.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'custom_woocommerce_after_cart_item_name');
function custom_woocommerce_after_cart_item_name($cart_item)
{
    echo '<br />Lead time can be up to 8 weeks.';
}
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'custom_woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity');
function custom_woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity($cart_item_quantity)
{
    $cart_item_quantity = $cart_item_quantity.'<br />Lead time can be up to 8 weeks.';
    return $cart_item_quantity;
}
```

If woocommerce blocks are used for cart page, checkout page, then following code can be put.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_wp_footer');
function custom_wp_footer()
{
    if(is_cart())
    {
        echo '<style type="text/css">.wc-block-cart-item__product .wc-block-components-product-price:after { content: "Lead time can be up to 8 weeks."; display: block; }</style>';
    }
    else if(is_checkout())
    {
        echo '<style type="text/css">.wc-block-components-order-summary-item__description .wc-block-components-product-price:after { content: "Lead time can be up to 8 weeks."; display: block; }</style>';
    }
}
```

It can be checked, if this code works.